# AES Encrypt/Decrypt SQL DB issue on decryption with Initialization Vector

Tags: android, kotlin, encryption, aes, initialization-vector

I am trying to store encrypted data in a SQL database using AES with Initialization Vector (IV). I am able to do this with the following class:

```
class Encrypted (wordE : String) {

val keyGenerator: KeyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES,"AndroidKeyStore")
val keyGenParameterSpec = KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder("MyKeyAlias",
KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT or KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
    .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC)
    .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_NONE)
    .build()

fun genKey(){
    keyGenerator.init(keyGenParameterSpec)
    keyGenerator.generateKey()
}

fun getKey(): SecretKey {
    genKey()
    val keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore")
    keystore.load(null)

    val secretKeyEntry = keystore.getEntry("MyKeyAlias", null) as KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry
    return secretKeyEntry.secretKey
}

fun encryptData(data: String): Pair<ByteArray, ByteArray> {
    val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding")

    var temp = data
    while (temp.toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8).size % 16 != 0)
        temp += "\u0020"

    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, getKey())

    val ivBytes = cipher.iv

    val encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(temp.toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8))
    return Pair(ivBytes, encryptedBytes)
}

val pair = encryptData(wordE)
val encrypted = pair.second.toString(Charsets.UTF_8)
val iv = pair.first
```

}

but I have some problems to decrypt the data from the database.
For decryption I have implemented another class:

```
class Decrypted (dataD: String, ivD :String) {

fun getKey(): SecretKey {
    val keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore")
    keystore.load(null)

    val secretKeyEntry = keystore.getEntry("MyKeyAlias", null) as KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry
    return secretKeyEntry.secretKey
}

fun decryptData(data: String, iv : String) : String {

    val spec = IvParameterSpec(iv.toByteArray())
    val decipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding")

    decipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, getKey(), spec)
    val encryptedData: ByteArray = data.toByteArray()

    return decipher.doFinal(encryptedData).toString().trim()
}
    val decryptedData = decryptData(dataD, ivD)
```

}

I understood that IV must be the same as the one generated during encryption, so I also stored IV in the database as .

From my logcat I get an "InvocationTargetException" to "Invalid IV" message.
I can see that when I call the Decrypted class enter for decryption:

> dataEncrypted: /�,@�j3�RqLrY�
>
> iv_stored: [B@5a36422

Comment: Have you considered using SQLCipher for Android?

Comment: Use base 64 to store the ciphertext, don't try to decode something that isn't a binary representation of text, or you may lose information. Note that using PKCS5Padding is highly recommended, padding with spaces is generally not done as you would be unable to decrypt messages that end with spaces (and I wonder how performant byte concatenation is in Kotlin).

Comment: @Maarten Bodewes thank you! I follow your suggestion and I solved my problem using Base64.